# Components.classes TcpSocket not defined in Firefox addon for Firefox 44

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, tcpsocket

I am writing a Firefox Addon.  It contains the code

```
var TcpSocket = Cc["@mozilla.org/tcp-socket;1"];
var tcpSocketListener = TcpSocket.createInstance(Ci.nsIDOMTCPSocket);
```

It works perfectly fine in Firefox 40.  However, when I run the same addon on Firefox 44, I get the error:

TypeError: TcpSocket is undefined

When I change the code to

```
var tcpSocketListener = Cc["@mozilla.org/tcp-socket;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIDOMTCPSocket);
```

I get the error:

TypeError: Cc['@mozilla.org/tcp-socket;1'] is undefined

According to Firefox, this error indicates the "extension tries to access a software interface that is no longer supported in the current releases"
however I am unclear on exactly what changed in Firefox that prevents me from using the old code and how to change it to work in the current version of Firefox.